# Laravel Task scheduling

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having some trouble with my scheduling tasks .Well i'm looping several users and i'm scheduling one task at every everyThirtyMinutes func.The problem is that the first task is not finished to run yet and again after 30 minutes it start again i just want to do that if user is not finished to run don't start a new task.

Comment: Can you post some code.

Comment: One way to do it would be to log the start/stop times in the database, then check for any tasks without a stop time when the script first runs.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `->withoutOverlapping()` to make sure that the tasks don't overlap.

```
$schedule->command('task')->everyThirtyMinutes()->withoutOverlapping();
```

Comment: Tried that and that was not helping me it just bring me all the users at once and not running